# Getting error while getting view of RecyclerView in onActivityCreated()

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am following a tutorial on [Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/course/learn-android-application-development-y/learn/lecture/11462570) using RecyclerView using Fragments. Everything works fine until this line 44 `recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rcl)`

I searched a lot on internet but did not get any solution related to this. I debugged the code and view was null. Either there was a problem in that tutorial or only i am having the problem.

1- Fragment_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ListFrag">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rcl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

2- ListFrag.jave

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rcl);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    adapter = new PersonAdapter(this.getActivity(), ApplicationClass.people);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

3- This is the Error :

```
Error :
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
            at com.example.recyclerfragments.ListFrag.onActivityCreated(ListFrag.java:44)
            at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2619)
            at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:904)
            at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
            at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
            at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2659)
            at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2613)
            at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:246)
            at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:542)
            at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:201)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1391)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7214)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3189)
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:185)
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:170)
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:147)
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:73)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2031)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7083)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:536)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:928)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is here:

```
recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rcl);
```

`view` is null.

Try to replace by:

```
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
    // Add this.. Here, view won't be null
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rcl);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    // recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rcl); --> Remove this from here.
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    adapter = new PersonAdapter(this.getActivity(), ApplicationClass.people);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Another options is replacing `view` by `getActivity()`:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    recyclerView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.rcl);
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

put your code in `onViewCreated()` this is for kotlin, for java just override the method and put your code in it

make sure your view object is globally declared so it will not be null after view created

like this:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rcl)
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.activity)
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager)
        adapter = PersonAdapter(this.activity, ApplicationClass.people)
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter)
    }
```

Comment: If it works, please accept the answer, so others will know

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing view in onCreateView but using view  recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rcl); in  onActivityCreated, thats why you are getting error.

There are multiple ways to resolve this error:

First One:

```
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rcl);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        adapter = new PersonAdapter(this.getActivity(), ApplicationClass.people);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return view;
        }
```

2nd :

```
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rcl);
        return view;
        }

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        adapter = new PersonAdapter(this.getActivity(), ApplicationClass.people);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```